# Equivalence of the LDL decomposition with an upper-triangular or lower-triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

I [am aware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#LDL_decomposition) that given a positive-definite matrix $A$ we can compute its LDL decomposition as:

$$ A = L D L^t $$

where $L$ is a lower unit triangular matrix and $D$ a diagonal matrix.

In this paper by ([Tong et al., 2019](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8755295)), they write:

> For an arbitrary positive-definite precision matrix $Ω$ , the modified Cholesky factorization can be written as
>
> $$ Ω = T^t D^{−1} T $$
>
> where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries, the modified Cholesky factor $T$ is a lower triangular matrix

In this formulation, the matrix $T$ is lower-triangular, so $T^t$ is *upper*-triangular. How can I obtain the matrices $T$ and $D^{-1}$ starting with a standard LDL decomposition of $Ω$? Is there a direct equivalence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a direct equivalence. Let $K$ denote the matrix of $1$'s on the "perdiagonal", i.e.
$$
K = \pmatrix{&&&1\\&&1\\&\cdots\\1},
$$
with the blank entries equal to zero. Note that $K = K^T = K^{-1}$, and that $M$ is upper triangular if and only if $KMK$ is lower triangular. In general, the change from $M$ to $KMK$ consists of reversing the order of both the rows and the columns of $M$.

Suppose that we want a decomposition of the form $\Omega = T^T D^{-1}T$. Begin by computing a decomposition $K\Omega K = L^TD_0 L$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
K\Omega K &= L^TD_0 L \implies\\
\Omega &= KL^TD_0 LK 
\\ & = KL^T(KK)D_0(KK)LK
\\ & = (KL^TK)(KD_0K)(KLK)
\\&= (KLK)^T (KD_0K)(KLK).
\end{align}
$$
Note that because $D_0$ is diagonal, $KD_0K$ is also diagonal (with its diagonal reverse relative to those of $D_0$). Taking $T = KLK$ and $D = (KD_0K)^{-1} = KD_0^{-1}K$, we have $\Omega = T^T D^{-1}T$, which is what we wanted.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! With a small note that if we start with $KΩK = L D_0 L^T$ as in the Wikipedia definition of LDL decomposition, we just need to take $T = (KLK)^T$ to obtain the result wanted.

Comment: @Alex Yes, that note is what my final paragraph was meant to communicate, sorry if that was unclear